# Writing a formula into an excel file using RODBC

Tags: excel, r, rodbc

I am able to write a data frame to an excel file, using the `RODBC` package.

Now I would like to include some formulas, e.g. `=A1`, which upon opening the excel file are interpreted as such; including "=A1" as text in the data frame results in a string entry "=A1" in the excel file (the value shown in the formula bar is `'=A1`), and is not interpreted as a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your file without quotes. When I constructed a tiny file named testcsv.csv with this as contents:

=B2, 2

... And then used the File/Open ... menu and used the dialog to open it after selecting All Files as the file type, the expected calculation occurs:

[image]

(This is on a Mac with Excel2011, <\strike> so Windoze might be different. <\strike>) Works the same on Excel 2007 running in WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using one of the CRAN packages interfacing xls file natively -- I had good luck with [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xlsx); others have reported success with [xlsReadWrite](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xlsReadWrite)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach in windows would be to use the `rcom` package http://rcom.univie.ac.at/.